# Case Related Lists in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, case, related-list

Does anyone know how I can pull Case related lists into a custom Visualforce page?  I know I can use the syntax:

```
<apex:relatedList list="NotesAndAttachments"/>
```

in other pages, however, I cannot get it to work on cases.  I am looking to add the related lists for:

**Emails

Related Cases

Solutions

Case Comments

Open Activities

Case History

Attachments**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following in `Execute Anonymous` to find the `Child Relationship` names.

```
DescribeSObjectResult describe = SObjectType.Case;
for (ChildRelationship relationship : describe.getChildRelationships())
    system.debug(relationship);
```

A naive copy to the `list` attribute yields:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <!--apex:relatedList list="EmailMessages" /-->
    <apex:relatedList list="Cases" />
    <apex:relatedList list="CaseSolutions" />
    <!--apex:relatedList list="CaseComments" /-->
    <apex:relatedList list="OpenActivities" />
    <apex:relatedList list="ActivityHistories" />
    <!--apex:relatedList list="Histories" /-->
    <!--apex:relatedList list="Attachments" /-->
</apex:page>
```

Commented out lists did not work. I will update with the missing names as I find them.

Comment: I believe you can't do relatedList on field histories on any sobject. So sad as it makes replacing OOB detail pages so difficult with VF when you want a mix of custom RL and OOB RL + apex:detail

Comment: @cropredy -- I was afraid of that.  Makes it more difficult to get the functionality I need.

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse Schema Browser at the Apex Explorer are great tools to help with this.

See attached screenshot.

[image: Relationship name]